# Least square solutions when $Ax=b$ has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this linear alegbra question that I don't know how to start.
The question:

$$A = \left( \begin{matrix}1 & -2 \\3 & 1  \\2 & 3  \\\end{matrix}\right ) $$

$$b= \left (\begin{matrix}
        0  \\
        1   \\
        0   \\
        \end{matrix}\right )$$

$$r = \left ( \begin{matrix}
        x \\
        y  \\
        \end{matrix} \right )$$

The matrix equation of $Ar-b$ has no solution because it is inconsistent. If we define the square error to be $\Delta^2 = \delta^T\delta$ where δ=Ar−b, we can still solve the least square sense.

Explain why $\Delta^2$ is a function of x and y and that $\Delta^2 $ is minimised by the solution of $$A^TAr = A^Tb$$

Need some guidance in solving this two parts.

Comment: Several things about your way of stating the problem are not clear.  You say "The matrix equation of $Ar-b$".  That is not an equation.  I surmise that you mean the equation $Ar-b=0$.  That could be stated explicitly.  By "solution", I likewise surmise that you mean "solution for $r$".  Again, you could say that.  Then you refer to $\delta^T\delta$.  You could have said "where $\delta=Ar-b$", which is again my surmise rather than what you said.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220571/set-of-all-points-in-3-space).

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$A^T A =  \left( \begin{matrix}1&3&2\\-2&1&3 \\\end{matrix}\right )  \left( \begin{matrix}1 & -2 \\3 & 1  \\2 & 3  \\\end{matrix}\right ) = \left ( \begin{matrix} 14 & 7\\ 7 & 14 \end{matrix} \right )$$
and
$$A^T b =  \left( \begin{matrix}1&3&2\\-2&1&3 \\\end{matrix}\right )  \left ( \begin{matrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{matrix} \right )= \left( \begin{matrix} 3\\1 \end{matrix} \right )$$
So we result in a $2\times 2$ linear equation system with an unique solution:
$$\left ( \begin{matrix} 14 & 7\\ 7 & 14 \end{matrix} \right ) r = \left( \begin{matrix} 3\\1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

So far for the solution. Now why is $\Delta^2$ a function of $r = (x,y)^T$? Well, because the definition says

$$\Delta^2 = (Ar-b)^T (Ar-b) = (Ar)^T(Ar) - (Ar)^T b - b^T Ar + b^Tb = r^T A^TA r - r^T A^Tb - b^T Ar + b^Tb = r^T (A^TAr-2A^Tb) + b^Tb$$
with constant $A, b$. Thus, $\Delta^2 = \Delta^2(r) = \Delta^2(x,y)$. Using the latter expanded form, minimizing $\Delta^2$ is the same as minimizing $r^T A^TAr - 2r^TA^Tb$. The rest is basic calculus.

Comment: how can Δ2 is minimised by the solution?

Comment: Compute the gradient of $\Delta^2(r)$ and so on...

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\min_r &\|Ar-b\|_2^2\\
\phi(r)&=(Ar-b)^T(Ar-b)\\
&=(r^TA^T-b^T)(Ar-b)\\
&=r^TA^TAr-r^TA^Tb-b^TAr+b^Tb\\
&=r^TA^TAr-2b^TAr+b^Tb\\
\text{We want to minimize }\phi (r)\\
\nabla\phi(r)&=0\\
\implies 2A^TAr-2A^Tb+0&=0 \qquad \text{ Reference For This Step Below}\\ 
\implies A^TAr&=A^Tb\\
&\blacksquare
\end{align}
Reference for [Matrix Calculus](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus&ei=wRMVUrukOuXn2wXaj4HYDA&usg=AFQjCNE6rr96Fns8PKKNvaoLEn5RK93fsw&bvm=bv.50952593,d.b2I)

You might also want to investigate a very powerful tool called the [Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Comment: You still need to prove that the critical point is necessarily a Minimum and neither a Maximum nor a Saddle(?)-Point (~$x^3$, don't know the english word)

Comment: @AlexR, agreed. I will add it later.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A^TA$ is invertible. Then consider the matrix $M=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T$. It is not hard to verify that
$$
M^2=M\tag{1}
$$ 
and
$$
M^T=M\tag{2}
$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ show that $M$ is an orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$. To see that it is onto the column space of $A$, note that $MA=A$. It is orthogonal because for any $x,y$
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Ax,My-y\rangle
&=\langle Ax,My\rangle-\langle Ax,y\rangle\\
&=\langle M^TAx,y\rangle-\langle Ax,y\rangle\\
&=\langle MAx,y\rangle-\langle Ax,y\rangle\\
&=\langle Ax,y\rangle-\langle Ax,y\rangle\\
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Since $Mb$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$, it should be the closest point to $b$ of any $Ax$. Therefore, let
$$
r=\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^Tb\tag{4}
$$
which is equivalent to the condition $A^TAr=A^Tb$.

$Ar=Mb$ should be the closest point to $b$ of any $Ax$. In fact, if we use $(4)$ and apply $(3)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|A(r+x)-b\|^2
&=\langle Mb+Ax-b,Mb+Ax-b\rangle\\
&=\|Mb-b\|^2+2\langle Ax,Mb-b\rangle+\|Ax\|^2\\
&=\|Ar-b\|^2+\|Ax\|^2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(5)$ shows that $\|A(r+x)-b\|^2$ is minimal iff $Ax=0$ and since $A^TA$ is invertible, $Ax=0\iff x=0$. Therefore, $(4)$ does give the least squares solution as implied by the orthogonality.

---

**Another Approach**

Consider
$$
\begin{align}
\|A(r+x)-b\|^2
&=\langle Ar+Ax-b,Ar+Ax-b\rangle\\
&=\langle Ar-b,Ar-b\rangle+2\langle Ar-b,Ax\rangle+\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\\
&=\|Ar-b\|^2+2\langle A^TAr-A^Tb,x\rangle+\|Ax\|^2\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Let $x=t(A^TAr-A^Tb)$, then $(6)$ says
$$
\|A(r+x)-b\|^2=\|Ar-b\|^2+2t\|A^TAr-A^Tb\|^2+t^2\|AA^TAr-AA^Tb\|^2\tag{7}
$$
For $\|Ar-b\|^2$ to be a minimum, the derivative of $(7)$ must equal $0$. That is, $\|A^TAr-A^Tb\|^2=0$

Therefore, for $\|Ar-b\|^2$ to be a minimum, we must have
$$
A^TAr-A^Tb=0\tag{8}
$$