# The least-squares solution for interval data

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to solve the least-squares for $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{y}$ with some values in $\mathbf{A}$ and also in $\mathbf{y}$ are interval-valued numbers. In a more detail, e.g.,:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & \underline{\overline{a}}_{22} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\
x_2 & 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\
y_2 & \\
\underline{\overline{y}}_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\underline{\overline{a}}_{22}$ means $\alpha_1 \le x_{22} \le \alpha_2$ and $\underline{\overline{y}}_3$ means $\beta_1 \le y_3\le \beta_2$, $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in\mathbb{R}$

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to solve the equation above? I have found several papers that deal with square A, but not the case above
2. Could anybody give clues or point references if the problem can be solved?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220571/set-of-all-points-in-3-space).

Comment: You have an over determined system.